# Case statement errors with unneccessary conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm currently scripting a view, shown below, but I'm experiencing some issues for the last five selects. I'm pulling from a table that is mostly int values but contains some NULLS. What I'd like is for any NULL values for these 'rep' columns to be outputted as 'N/A' however some logic in the case statements are throwing errors trying to convert the N/A to INT.

I think somewhere along the line in the case statements, it's setting the NULLS to N/A and then trying to add values onto it as INT but would appreciate some help as to where it might be falling over.

Many thanks!

```
SELECT
--Name
ExerciseCultures.Name,
--Weight
CASE
  WHEN weight IS NULL THEN '0'
  ELSE
    CASE
      WHEN Type = 'Isolation' THEN
        CASE
          WHEN reps1 < '12'
               AND reps2 < '12'
               AND reps3 < '12' THEN weight
          ELSE
            CASE
              WHEN exercisecultures.name IN ( 'Hammer Curls', 'Concentration Curls' ) THEN workoutsessions.weight + ( 2.0 )
              ELSE WorkoutSessions.weight + ( 2.5 )
            END
        END
      ELSE
        CASE
          WHEN Type = 'Compound' THEN
            CASE
              WHEN name = 'Bench Press' THEN
                CASE
                  WHEN reps1 < '3'
                       AND reps2 < '3'
                       AND reps3 < '3' THEN weight
                  ELSE workoutsessions.weight + ( 2.5 )
                END
              ELSE
                CASE
                  WHEN reps1 < '5'
                       AND reps2 < '5'
                       AND reps3 < '5' THEN weight
                  ELSE workoutsessions.weight + ( 2.5 )
                END
            END
        END
    END
END AS Weight,
-- Reps1
CASE
  WHEN Reps1 = NULL THEN 'N/A'
  ELSE
    CASE
      WHEN Type = 'Isolation' THEN
        CASE
          WHEN reps1 < '12'
               AND reps1 >= '8' THEN reps1 + ( 1 )
          ELSE '8'
        END
      ELSE '5'
    END
END AS Reps1,
-- Reps2
CASE
  WHEN Reps2 IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
  ELSE
    CASE
      WHEN Type = 'Isolation' THEN
        CASE
          WHEN reps2 < '12'
               AND reps2 >= '8' THEN reps2 + ( 1 )
          ELSE '8'
        END
      ELSE '5'
    END
END AS Reps2,
--Reps3
CASE
  WHEN Reps3 IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
  ELSE
    CASE
      WHEN Type = 'Isolation' THEN
        CASE
          WHEN reps3 < '12'
               AND reps3 >= '8' THEN reps3 + ( 1 )
          ELSE '8'
        END
      ELSE '5'
    END
END AS Reps3,
--Reps4
CASE
  WHEN Reps4 IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
  ELSE
    CASE
      WHEN Type = 'Isolation' THEN
        CASE
          WHEN reps4 < '12'
               AND reps4 >= '8' THEN reps4 + ( 1 )
          ELSE '8'
        END
      ELSE '5'
    END
END AS Reps4,
--Reps5
CASE
  WHEN Reps5 IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
  ELSE
    CASE
      WHEN Type = 'Isolation' THEN
        CASE
          WHEN reps5 < '12'
               AND reps5 >= '8' THEN reps5 + ( 1 )
          ELSE '8'
        END
      ELSE '5'
    END
END AS Reps5
FROM   workoutsessions
       JOIN exercisecultures
         ON workoutsessions.ExerciseID = ExerciseCultures.ExerciseID
       JOIN workoutdates
         ON workoutsessions.WorkoutID = Workoutdates.WorkoutID
            AND workoutdates.date = (SELECT Max(date)
                                     FROM   WorkoutDates
                                     WHERE  workouttype = 'Pull')
```

Comment: thats exactly the problem, one column can only have one Type. Convert all the values to VARCHAR, so you can have 'N/A' and '1' on the same column. Example.: CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),reps1+(1))

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the integer types, to varchar types before doing your conditional statements. You can do this by either creating a variable/temp table, specifying those columns to be VARCHAR - and then extracting data from this temporary table OR if you do not want to do that, you will have to cast each integer column in your query like this...

```
    case when CAST(Reps1 AS varchar(100)) = Null then 'N/A'
    else
```